# Helm Charts: How to install a package in a K0s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kube-apiserver, k0s

I am aiming to install a `helm package` in a `k0s cluster` throught the use of the following command:

```
helm install name . --kube-apiserver=x.x.x.x:xxx
```

But I get the following output:

> Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get
> "http://x.x.x.x:xxx/version?timeout=32s": dial tcp x.x.x.x:x: connect:
> connection refused

I am wondering:

1. what is the right syntax for `--kube-apiserver` ?
2. why the server is rejecting the request ?
3. how to resolve it ?

Comment: You shouldn't need that option at all.  Do basic commands like `kubectl get pods` work?  Helm will use the same configuration to reach the cluster.

Comment: @DavidMaze : Thanks for reply, but your answer doesn't work with `K0s`. The reason is that `kubectl` runs as a sub-process of the `K0s` and hence `helm` needs to talk to `k0s` first before talking to the `cluster`. That is why you have to specify the `--kube-apisever` stated in the `K0s admin.config file`  (unlike k8s where kubectl allows you to communicate directly with the k8s cluster)

Comment: Can you [set $KUBECONFIG to point to the k0s configuration](https://docs.k0sproject.io/v1.21.0+k0s.0/FAQ/#how-do-i-connect-to-the-cluster)?  (That FAQ entry suggests copying the file and setting the API server address in the copy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue, and followed the instructions at https://www.mirantis.com/blog/how-to-set-up-k0s-kubernetes-a-quick-and-dirty-guide/ :

```
sudo cp /var/lib/k0s/pki/admin.conf ~/admin.conf
export KUBECONFIG=~/admin.conf
```

I add to ensure that `admin.conf` was owned by my user and didn't have group read:

```
sudo chown <user> ./admin.conf
chmod g-r ./admin.conf
```

Then `helm install` worked